# Examples of comonoids (coalgebras) in the stable homotopy category $\mathbf{SH}$

Tags: stable-homotopy, motives, motivic-homotopy, ring-spectra, stable-homotopy-category

My question is both for the topological and for the algebraic/motivic version of the stable homotopy category $\mathbf{SH}$.

It is well known that most cohomologies are represented in $\mathbf{SH}$ by certain spectra which are **monoids** (also called ring spectra in this setting). This means that $K$-theory, motivic and singular cohomology, cobordism cohomologies, etc... are represented by certain spectra $\mathbb{E}$ that are endowed with maps
$$
\mu \colon \mathbb{E}\otimes \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{E} \ \ \mbox{ and }\ \ e\colon \mathbb{1}\to \mathbb{E}\ ,
$$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the unit object in $\mathbf{SH}$ for the tensor product, satisfying certain axioms ([check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory))). The $\mu$ is called multiplication, and induces the cup and cap products, and $e$ is called the unit and correspond to the unit of the cohomology.

A **comonoid** (or coalgebra) in $\mathbf{SH}$ is an object $\mathbb{F}$ which is a monoid in the opposite category $\mathbf{SH}^\mathrm{op}$. In other words, $\mathbb{F}$ is endowed with maps
$$
\Delta \colon \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F} \otimes \mathbb{F} \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \xi \colon \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{1} \ ,
$$
satisfying certain axioms.

My question is:

> **Are there relevant examples of comonoids (coalgebras) in either the algebraic/motivic or the topological version of $\mathbf{SH}$?**

Comment: By "algebraic" SH, do you mean the stable motivic category?

Comment: Yes, I mean Voevodsky's stable homotopy category in the $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy setting

Comment: They’re fairly common: every suspension spectrum gives a comonoid, and a lesser known theorem of Bousfield says that in the K(n)-local category every spectrum admits such a structure. The “Thom diagonal” is an adjacent concept, presenting a Thom spectrum as a cotorsor for the comonoid associated to the suspension spectrum of the base space. I don’t know whether there’s an out-and-out classification available.

Comment: Also the Koszul duals of augmented monoids and descent corings.